# How do I get this chest in the Abandoned Factory?

Tags: nier-automata

I feel like I figured it out my first play through the game, but in my current save file, I haven't been able to figure it out.

[image]

It's right outside of the Factory: Hanger access point.

Comment: Can you not just go up the way that the map shows? There's an opening just to the right.

Comment: @Vemonus What do you mean?  The stairs are in the way.

Comment: The minimap makes it look like there's a gap between what I guess are stairs and the platform that the chest is on. Is there not a way to jump between them?

Comment: @Vemonus No, if you jump from the platform to the right of the chest, you hit the stairs and fall.  The bottom of the stairs is just below the bottom of both platforms.  I haven't found a way to jump high enough to grab the platform either.  I tried jump from the platform, floating, then air sprinting (evade key) and jump again, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few ways to pull it off, but there are two shared pieces of the strategy: You must walk off the right platform, and you must mix in an aerial attack or dash; you can't just jump.

I found a [video demonstrating how to reach the chest](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c6Ftzf2Z9oA) with a dash and double jump. Every character can aerial dash and double jump, so you shouldn't have a problem regardless of who you are currently playing.