# Two chests in factory - possible to get or incorrectly marked?

Tags: nier-automata

If you have the Item Scan chip equipped, in Chapter 9 there's a part of the factory where the view changes to side scrolling and zooms very far out.  After you go through the middle tower there's a chest mark on the mini-map which appears to be near the top.

When you go through as 9S later controlling a flying machine (in the opposite direction) if you go through the same middle tower and fly up higher, you can see another (different) chest indicator.

It seems like as you go through the factory you can backtrack later when you've climbed the towers a bit.

> I've already gotten the weapon worshipped by the cult machines, as well as the 9S chest in a room that also has a large chest, a small chest, and an endless supply of suicide robots.

Any idea what how to get them?  Possibly one is from this question? [How do i get this chest in the factory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/309024/how-do-i-get-this-chest-in-the-factory)

Comment: A picture would probably help here.

Comment: @Vemonus I thought i had made some screen grabs when I posted this, but I forgot to upload them from the PS4. I'll do that next time I play.